# Network Analysis of Multiple points

Tags: qgis, network, distance-matrix

Is it possible to do a network analysis along a path (road) from multiple points to one point in QGIS?

I am trying to calculate the distance from the center of various suburbs to the city center.

The [Network Analysis Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html) seems like an answer, but I have 55 origins, so would like a programmatic solution if it exists.

I have centroids for the polygons, and have set the tolerance on the Network Analysis tool to deal with the distance to the road.

Is it possible to modify this tool in QGIS? Should I use a different technique altogether?